# Is it possible to initialize multiple Javascript arrays in a loop?

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have a for loop and i want to initialize multiple arrays in that loop. Can it be achieved like this?:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var array+i = [];
}
```

So that the arrays that will be created are array0,array1,array2,array3,array4?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a multi dimensional array to tackle this problem:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  var array[i]=[];
}
```

which will result in:

```
array[0] = []
array[1] = []
array[2] = []
array[3] = []
array[4] = []
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve *something* like that using

- [JavaScript Two Dimensional
  Arrays](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-two-dimensional-arrays.html)
- [Building a MultiDimensional Array in
  Javascript](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2310/building-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascript/)
- [JavaScript Multi-Dimensional
  Arrays](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12455)
- [JavaScript: Multi-dimensional
  Array](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/javascript-multi-dimensional-array.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it out,

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
 eval("var array"+i+"=[];");
}
```

But eval is evil, it would make much more sense to just use a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of arrays:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
}
```

Or if it must be a global variable (probably not a good idea):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    window["array" + i] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [two dimensional array](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Array2D.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Example to initialize 10 empty arrays:

```
let subArrays = Array.from({length: 10}, () => []);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're in a browser and willing to do something hacky you can use the top-level object, namely `window`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  window["array" + i] = [];
}
```

After doing this, you'll be able to refer to each array as `array1` or whichever number you want.

This said, you should probably never actually use this method.